# Xcode 6 Beta projects compatibility with Xcode 6

Tags: xcode6, xcode6-beta7

Will my Xcode 6 Beta project be fully supported in Xcode 6 (final version). Like, I create an Xcode 6 Beta project and I get really into it, I don't want to have to create a whole new project over again once Xcode 6 comes out. Can someone put me to ease about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the legitimate version of Xcode 6 Beta you will be just fine. When you download the official Xcode it should look to the same folder for your previous/ current projects.

Comment: Cool! So I can start on a project in Xcode 6 beta6 and then when my Xcode 6 beta7 gets through downloading I can delete my Xcode 6 beta6 and open that same project in newly downloaded Xcode 6 beta7 (and thus the same with the full Xcode 6 when it comes out) and I shouldn't have to worry about my project being F'd up?